# get challenge with arduino nfc MFRC522 module from an epassport

Tags: arduino, nfc, rfid

I am working with my Ardunio and the contactless reader/writer MFRC522 from NXP. I am using my ePassport (EU standard) and I want to start the **Basic Access Control** (BAC) procedure by sending the `Get Challenge APDU` command to its RFID chip.

Here in stackoverflow I found the APDU `00 84 00 00 08`. To implement it on my Ardunio project I use the library of *miguelbalboa* (accessed [here](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid)). Within this library there is a method to send data to an RFID chip and store its response. But first I get the ATQA which is the ATR equivalent to a contact card (which is in my case `00 08`) and then a SAK (which is in my case `20`). The library notes that it detected PICC compliant with **ISO/IEC 14443-4** in my ePassport and finally I get its randomized UID. Next step I try to get the challenge with

```
// create MFRC522 instance „mfrc522“
// Init SPI bus 
// Init MFRC522 device
// Select RFID chip (PICC_Select method)
byte sendData[] = {0x00, 0x84, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08};
byte backLen = 10; // I know that the answer (= the challenge) is 8 bytes long + 2 bytes for SW1 + SW2
byte sendLen = sizeof(sendData);
byte backData[backLen];
MFRC522::StatusCode status = mfrc522.PCD_TransceiveData(sendData, sizeof(sendData), backData, &backLen);
// Print „status“
```

No matter what I do/change/extend, the StatusCode returned is always

> Timeout in communication

and I can’t find out: What am I doing wrong? I am now doubting that it is a programming error but maybe rather a hardware issue? Maybe the **FIFO buffer** on the **MFRC522** does not accept this command although I didn’t find any restrictions in its [technical specs](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MFRC522.pdf) but then I am thinking: all I do is sending and receiving bytes according to the **ISO/IEC 7816-4** standard with an **ISO/IEC 14443-4** contactless RFID chip…

EDIT: I tried the APDU command with my NFC device in my smartphone and an **APDU Debug** app from Google Play Store and there it works fine! So the chip or the APDU command itself can’t be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending a T=1 block?

The Block format PCB|CID|INF|EDC. This is described in http://read.pudn.com/downloads64/ebook/225463/M305_DESFireISO14443.pdf

I had success sending the GetVersion to DESFire but it timeout trying to fetch the next frame (0xAF)